# Using Ubuntu VM on remote windows computer. Choosing VboxVGA gives me an offset cursor, Choosing VmsVGA won't autoresize window

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

```
I have a problem running Ubuntu 14.x (no choice) in a VM on a client's computer which I access via RDP:

When I select "VboxVGA", my mouse cursor is display to the right and lower of the actual cursor position as detected by hotspot highlighting or text select or window resize, etc.

But if I use "VmsVGA", the cursor tracks well, but I have use `xrandr --size 1680x1050` to get the screen to expand.  When I look at the view menu, `View->Auto-resize Guest Display` is grayed out.
```

Either solution would be acceptable:

1. (In VboxVGA) "Why is my cursor pointer is offset to the right and down from where linux thinks it is?"
2. (In VmsVGA) "Why won't VmsVGA allow autosizing?"

And yes VboxVGA DOES Autosizing, and VmsVGA puts the cursor in the right place.

I'd love a solution for both, but either will do.

Comment: Did you install the VBOX Extensions in Ubuntu?  You would need these.

Comment: Is that separate from the Guest Additions?  I'm using the same image for both tests, just changing the display setting in preferences.   The autosize from guest additions works for VboxVGA.

Comment: Guest Additions are the VBOX Extensions. If installed and set up then your video in the Guest should be better. Try reinstalling the Guest Additions to see.

Comment: @John  As I said, the Guest Additions are installed and doing the auto-sizing fine for VboxVGA, but not for VMSVGA.  But I can't use VboxVGA because the cursor icon is not at the same position as is being registered.  VMSVGA does good cursor tracking, but I have to resize the monitor manually with xrandr.

Comment: I know additions are installed. My second comment was to uninstall and then reinstall the additions to see. Restart the guest in between uninstall and reinstall.